# "Файл не найден" при копировании файла с русскими символами или пробелами в пути

Tags: c#, wpf

Изначальный путь к файлу: `C:\Users\101\Pictures\Снимок экрана 2023-02-15 115721.png`
Получаю путь к файлу от пользователя с помощью

```cs
var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
var PickedFilePath = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(dialog.FileName));
```

В `PickedFilePath.AbsolutePath` в итоге лежит такой путь: `C:\Users\101\Pictures\%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202023-02-15%20115721.png`
и при попытке выполнить копирование

```cs
var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(PickedFilePath.AbsolutePath);
Directory.CreateDirectory(Globals.ImagesPath);
var file = new FileInfo(PickedFilePath.AbsolutePath);
file.CopyTo(Globals.ImagesPath + "\\" + "copy" + fileExt, true);
```

получаю ошибку

> Файл 'C:\Users\101\Pictures%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202023-02-15%20115721.png' не найден.

Тоже самое происходит, если в пути есть пробелы. Сначала заменял через `.Replace('%20', " ")`, но с русскими символами делать такого не вижу смысла, должны же быть другие пути?

При копировании файлов только с английскими символами или цифрами без пробелов в пути все копируется без ошибок. Как копировать файлы с русскими символами и пробелами в пути? Может строку `PickedFilePath` можно форматировать какой-то встроенной функцией?

Comment: А нафига тут Uri? Он возвращает путь в escape-кодировке, само собой всё напрочь ломается. Это ж имя файла, а не веб-адрес...

Comment: @Akina `Uri` можно использовать для путей на диске, просто это надо делать с умом. Но здесь оно и вправду не требуется.

Comment: @aepot Да понятно, что это надо делать до обращения к файлу, ибо сам файловый реквестор не будет де-эскейпить путь, с его точки зрения это легальное имя совсем другого файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно либо раскодировать строку перед использованием, убрать URL Encoding

```
var file = new FileInfo(Uri.UnescapeDataString(PickedFilePath.AbsolutePath));
```

Либо не использовать `Uri`.

```
var PickedFilePath = dialog.FileName; // dialog.FileName возвращает абсолютный путь
var file = new FileInfo(PickedFilePath);
```

---

Кстати, научитесь использовать `Path.Combine`

```
file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(Globals.ImagesPath, "copy" + fileExt), true);
```